# Setting UNIQUE constraint on TIMESTAMP (WITH TIME ZONE)

Tags: postgresql

I want to scrape a table from a website and synchronize the data into my own database i.o. to detect whenever there is a new entry available. The table has a timestamp column which tells me when the new record was created.

However, I have different tables for multiple objects so in order to know if there is a new entry, I'd need a unique-constraint on `(object_id, timestamp)`:

```
object_id  | timestamp           | value
------------------------------------------
1          | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 100      <--|
1          | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 101         | error: have an
1          | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 102         | equal timestamp
1          | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 103      <--| 
2          | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | 1002
2          | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 | 1003
```

It feels a  bit odd to have such a unique-constraint so I was wondering if this is the only (or best) way I could do this?

Comment: Create according UNIQUE index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Time is included. In this example it just happens to be `00:00:00` for readability

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having a multi-column constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE mytab ADD PRIMARY KEY (object_id, timestamp);
```

The column order does not matter for the constraint, but if you more often search by `timestamp` alone, put that column first.